# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a common service to show a MatSnackBar. But somehow it is not able to load MatSnackBar.

If I directly inject MatSnackBar in the component it works fine but not when injected in the service class.

[image]

In the above code if we uncomment the lines from 24 to 28 and comment line 30 to 34 then it will work fine.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xqpukn?file=src%2Fexample%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.ts) I created. Please open the console to see errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your service is provided in root, so it's injector is the `RootInjector`.

So you need to provide the `ManSnackBar` provider in the `RootInjector`. By adding it to your standalone component you're only providing in the `NodeInjector` (the components injector).

To do that add it to the providers in `boostrapApplication`:

```
importProvidersFrom([ /* other modules */, MatSnackBarModule])
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the explanation.